# Насколько подробно обрабатывать исключения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно заворачивать код в блок try/except, если ошибка может произойти в каждой строке?

Я представляю два предельных случая.
1:

```
def show_phone(self, link):
    try:
        self.driver.get(link);
        hide_phone_el = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.hide_phone_selector)
        hide_phone_el.click()
    except SomeException as e:
        print('error', e)
```

2:

```
def show_phone(self, link):
    try:
        self.driver.get(link);
    except DriverException as e:
        print('error', e)

    try:
        hide_phone_el = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.hide_phone_selector)
    except AttributeException as e:
        print('error', e)

    try:
        hide_phone_el.click()
    except ClickException as e:
        print('error', e)
```

Второй случай надёжнее, но мне трудно представить среднюю/большую программу, написанную в таком стиле. Её невозможно будет читать.

Первый же случай не даёт полного представления о произошедшей ошибке. При этом можно создать свой тип исключения для первого случая. Однако, в результате всё равно будет непонятно с чем конкретно была связана ошибка(с кликом, с операцией присваивания или с ошибкой метода в driver)

Какими соображениями нужно руководствоваться при написании подобного кода? Существуют бест практисес?

Comment: Делайте traceback.print_exc() и там будет вся информация. Второй случай абсолютно бессмысленный: если hide_phone_el не создастся, то дальше у вас будет ошибка несуществующей переменной и необработанное исключение

Answer (score 1):

На один `try` можно делать несколько `except`:

```
def show_phone(self, link):
    try:
        self.driver.get(link);
        hide_phone_el = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.hide_phone_selector)
        hide_phone_el.click()
    except DriverException as e:
        print('error', e)
    except AttributeException as e:
        print('error', e)
    except ClickException as e:
        print('error', e)
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вопрос не об этом. А о том, что такой принт скрывает информацию, *где именно* случилась ошибка (похоже, автор не знает про traceback)

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы записали мой второй пример немного иначе, но суть осталась та же. Пресдставтье, что у нас есть блок из 10 строк кода. В каждой из этих строк может произойти ошибка. По-вашему нужно добавить к коду 10 эксепшенов. В результате получим код, который очень трудно читать человеку

Comment: Честно говоря, не вижу никаких трудностей. Вот читать десять блоков try-except подряд действительно тяжело.

Comment: @Эникейщик мы подошли к вопросу вкуса. Кому-то так удобно, кому-то по-другому. Но всё равно, если программа состоит из 1000 строк, а программисту приходится иметь дело минимум с 4000(специально предельный случай беру), то это не нормально. Должны существовать какие-нибудь правила, которые скажут оборачивать строку в блок try или нет

Comment: Если в программе из 1000 строк в каждой строке может случится исключение, то скорее всего эту программу можно удалить, а вместо нее написать другую, где исключений может быть всего четыре. На самом деле, случаев, где без исключений не обойтись, не так уж и много. А правила простые - если возможно исключение и вы не хотите, чтобы ваша программа в этом месте обвалилась, то нужно это исключение отлавливать. Даже если вам трудно читать такой код.

Comment: @Эникейщик вы ведь понимаете, что вы сейчас отправили в мусорку **абсолютно каждую** программу на Python?

Comment: @rettoryh13 правило простое и очевидное: если исключение в строке нужно обработать каким-то особым образом, то оборачивать; если не нужно — не оборачивать. Если задача — просто уведомить пользователя о случившейся ошибке, то одного-единственного блока с try-except Exception as e на всю программу вполне достаточно, а в этом except можно вывести всю нужную информацию

Comment: @andreymal Если у вас на каждую строку стоит try..except, то да, такие программы можно сразу в мусорку.

Comment: @Эникейщик я не про try-except, а про «может случиться исключение». В Python **не бывает** строк кода, в которых **не** может случиться исключение. (Не считая недостижимого кода, который никода не запускается)

Comment: @andreymal Во-первых, бывает, конечно же. А во-вторых, если вы так пишете, что программа может обвалиться в любой строке, то да - в мусорку. Прочитайте весь мой комментарий, а не только про "может случиться исключение". 99% всех эти "может случиться" исправляются уже на этапе написания/отладки. Можно, конечно, каждый ``range(x)`` заворачивать в try..except TypeError, мало ли, вдруг в `´x`` окажется строка. Но не лучше ли писать так, чтобы там строка не оказывалась?

Comment: @Эникейщик не могли бы вы показать пример кода, в котором никогда ни при каких условиях не может возникнуть исключение?

Comment: @andreymal ``s = [x for x in range(5)]``

Comment: @Эникейщик разумеется здесь возможен KeyboardInterrupt, а если постараться, то и MemoryError. Так что нет.

Comment: @andreymal Я правильно понимаю, что вы всегда и везде отлавливаете эти два исключения?

Comment: @Эникейщик да: KeyboardInterrupt я отлавливаю вместе с SystemExit для корректного завершения программы, а MemoryError я отлавливаю в "except Exception", чтобы записать ошибку в лог и (опционально) отправить уведомление на почту об упавшей программе. (Если скрипт маленький одноразовый, то могу не отлавливать, но это редко)

Comment: @andreymal Как часто случается? Я очень редко использую исключения (в основном при обращении к периферии) и не наблюдаю проблем.

Comment: @Эникейщик KeyboardInterrupt или SystemExit — всегда, когда я набираю `systemctl stop python-service-name.service` или `reboot` :) MemoryError в отдельности меня не интересует, я ловлю любые ошибки сразу, а их хватает https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E1J1.png

Comment: @Эникейщик но вы же понимаете, что из одного случая нельзя сделать статистики?

Comment: @rettoryh13 Никто и не делает.